# Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Attempt to get native tag from node not marked as "native" - React Navigation update causing crash

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

It seems an update or something else inexplicit in nature has caused my application to crash. Whenever I load a component or view that is animated (Scroll view, section list, etc) the application itself will simply crash with the following error.

```
[tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Attempt to get native tag from node not marked as "native"

This error is located at:
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.js:41)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.js:26)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.js:506)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.js:40)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.js:19)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:59)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:11)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
    in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at createTabNavigator.js:10)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in ResourceSavingScene (at createBottomTabNavigator.js:76)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in TabNavigationView (at createTabNavigator.js:135)
    in NavigationView (at createNavigator.js:59)
    in Navigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
    in NavigationContainer (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.js:481)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.js:41)
    in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.js:26)
    in Container (at StackViewLayout.js:506)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
    in withOrientation (at StackView.js:40)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.js:19)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:59)
    in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:11)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:36)
    in Root (at renderApplication.js:32)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in RCTView (at View.js:43)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:31)
```

I have tried so far:

- Removing the node_modules and *npm install* to get them back
- Googled this with bizzare and varied results
- Restarted my computer
- Cleared the xcode build folder
- Used the react-native updater as suggested by react native themselves in an attempt to update if that was the issue (seemed to have updated, still crashes)

My current specs etc:

- Latest Mac OSX
- Latest xcode
- Latest Node + NPM
- iPhone device to test on

Answer (score 1):

The answer apprently is an issue with react navigation as discussed here:
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4886

I reverted my react navigation version with

> yarn add react-navigation@2.11.2

and rebuilt and it works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

npm install react-navigation@2.11.2

and it will work fine, I tried it and it is working fine